# jQuery ajax success anonymous function scope

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I update the returnHtml variable from within the anonymous success function?

```
function getPrice(productId, storeId) {
    var returnHtml = '';

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            returnHtml = html;
        }
    });

    return returnHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

That is the wrong approach. The first A in AJAX is Asynchronous. That function returns before the AJAX call returns (or at least it can). So this is not an issue of scope. It is an issue of ordering. There are only two options:

1. Make the AJAX call synchronous (***not recommended***) with the [`async: false`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option; or
2. Change your way of thinking. Instead of returning HTML from the function you need to pass a callback to be called when the AJAX call succeeds.

As an example of (2):

```
function findPrice(productId, storeId, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            // Invoke the callback function, passing the html
            callback(productId, storeId, html);
        }
    });

    // Let the program continue while the html is fetched asynchronously
}

function receivePrice(productId, storeId, html) {
    // Now do something with the returned html
    alert("Product " + productId + " for storeId " + storeId + " received HTML " + html);
}

findPrice(23, 334, receivePrice);
```

Comment: Gotchya - I figured i have to do that.  but what if i had to do it?

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing how you intended to use the getPrice() method. What's it used for? How is it used? It's code at that "outer" level that will need to adjust.

Comment: Ok i got it.   I didn't realize that productId and storeId would be in the scope and I can actually pass that stuff into the call back.

Comment: @cletus You cannot say not recommended. It is not recommended only when user needs not know that a request is made. But there are situations where async:false is needed. In a situation where user shall not be allowed to proceed or trigger another event, it is necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer, you can't, the first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous, which means the request is still going when you get to the return statement.

You **can** do it with a synchronous (non-async) request, but it's generally a **Bad Thing**

Something like the following oughta return the data.

```
function getPrice(productId, storeId) {
  var returnHtml = '';

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
      returnHtml = html;
    }
  });

  return returnHtml;
}
```

---

**BUT**

Unless you really really need to be able to use the return value from test straight away, you'll be **much** better off passing a callback into test. Something like

```
function getPrice(productId, storeId, callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
      callback(html);
    }
  });
}

//the you call it like
getPrice(x,y, function(html) {
    // do something with the html
}
```

**Edit** Sheesh, you guys are quicker to say what I said :-)

Comment: Will setting `async: false` block page rendering by the browser ?

Answer (score 13):

Your anonymous function there *does* have access to the `returnHtml` variable in its scope, and so the code there is actually working as you'd expect. Where you're probably going wrong is in your return statement.

Remember that the **A** in **AJAX** stands for `asynchronous`, which means that it doesn't happen at the same time. For that reason, the line `returnHtml = html` is actually happening **after** you call `return returnHtml;`, so `returnHtml` is still an empty string.

It's hard to say what you should do to get this working as you want without seeing the rest of your code, but what you could do is add another callback to the function:

```
function getPrice(productId, storeId, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: callback
    });
}

getPrice(5, 1, function(html) {
    alert(html);
});
```