# in which scieno i need to use async: false, or async: true in Jquery Ajax Method

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i am wondering where i need to use `async: false, or  async: true`  Jquery Ajax Method

i have one form with  fields and when i click on button i am calling jquery ajax method to save value from this fields to server

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "../Member/Home.aspx/SaveClient",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: "{'projectSoid': '" + $("#hdnValueProjectSoid").val()
                            + "', 'name': '" + Name
                            + "', 'industry ': '" + Industry
                            + "', 'descriptions ': '" + Descriptions
                            + "', 'employment ': '" + Employment
                            + "', 'email  ': '" + Email
                            + "', 'phone  ': '" + Phone + "'}",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.d != null) {

                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

here are the use cases.
from the docs.

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Async

1. when you are doing Cross Domain Request.
2. this is the default setting for $.ajax.

Sync :

1. When you want to finish the request of ajax call i.e means one request after another. which is not recomennded.

[Async in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Async : The ajax response you are trying to get has no dependency on next task you are doing.

Sync: The ajax response you are trying receive has dependency on the next task you are doing.