# Set variable value on success

Tags: javascript, ajax

how can I set the variable `dch` to be the returned success ajax data?

```
var aid='11111111V';
var dch = 0;
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"new_hpa_fun_aplcval.php",
    data:"aid="+aid,
    success: function(msg) {            
        if (msg =='OK'){
            dch=1;                    
        } else {
            dch=2;
        }
    }
});
if (dch==1){
     //same php code
}else if (dch==2){
     //another php code
}
```

Comment: understand javascript callbacks.. you need to do that only in the success function

Comment: another way could be set async:false in the object that  you pass. But that's incorrect way of doing things

Comment: What do you mean with `//same php code` ?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: It's not an understanding of JavaScript callbacks that is needed, it's an understanding of asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Cory: Yes and that is where the effect of callback in this context is seen prominently

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal. That's true, but what @ABShaman needs to understand is that his `if-else` check is being executed *before* the AJAX POST has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are unfamiliar with asynchronous operations. In your code, your `if-else` check at the bottom of your code is actually executing *before* your `success` callback.

What you are probably observing is that `dch` is always `0`. You instead need to continue the execution of your code *inside the callback*:

```
var aid='11111111V';
var dch = 0;
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"new_hpa_fun_aplcval.php",
    data:"aid="+aid,
    success: function(msg) {            
        if (msg =='OK'){
            // perform something here                    
        } else {
            // perform something here
        }
    }
});
```

In this case, you don't even need the `dch` variable.

Your other option is to make the AJAX call *synchronous* by adding `async: false` to the options in the `$.ajax` method. This will cause your code to block and wait for the response before it continues executing.

See the [Wiki on Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for a more technical description of what's happening under the hood of jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

1) Wrap the ajax within a function and return the value

2) [What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

```
function call() {
     var temp = 0;
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"new_hpa_fun_aplcval.php",
        async: false,  // Add this
        data:"aid="+aid,
        success: function(msg) {            
            if (msg =='OK'){
                temp = 1;                    
            } else {
                temp = 2;
            }
        }           
     });
     return temp;
    }        
var dch = call();
```

Comment: `return` statements in asynchronous callbacks have no effect. This won't work.

Comment: @Pointy Oh ok I didn't see it.  So adding `ajax = false` will solve the problem right?  please correct me if I meant wrong

Comment: @user1671639: No. You would have to add `async: false`, and in addition, create a variable at the top of the function. In the `success` callback, you would set that variable, and finally, return the variable at the bottom (outside of the success callback).

Comment: It could be made synchronous, but even then the `return` value from the callback will be completely ignored by jQuery.  The "call" function has no `return` statement at all, so "dch" will always end up `undefined`.

Comment: @Cory Yes I agree with you point of using variable to return values.  But `return 1` and `return 2` will work right?  I can't understand why it will not work.  Please clarify this?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the feedback.  But I have the return statement, ` return 1; ` and ` return 2; ` This will work right.  Please clarify it?

Comment: **No it will not work.** Your `return` statements are **inside the callback function**, and the returned values will be ignored.

Comment: @Pointy I got it.  Just realized because of word "CALLBACK".  Thanks for taking time to respond to comments.