# It seems like loadtext property in jeditable doesn't work when waiting for select dropdown items from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, jeditable

I am using [jeditable and i am loading a select dropdown](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) from my server (it takes a few seconds to load via ajax) and i want to display a loading image or text while the ajax call is running so people know that the dropdown list is being loaded from the server.

I see there is the "indicator" property to show a loading image or text when saving the value to the server (which works perfect) but for some reason there is no working option to set a loading message when you are loading items for the select dropdown.

When i look into the plugin, i see a "loadtext" property that seems like it should be doing this but when i click on my text i don't see this "Loading . ." text displayed when it kicks off the ajax query to get the list of dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#person').editable('/Project/UpdatePerson', {
        loadurl: '/Project/GetPeople',
        type: 'select',
        loadtext: '<b>Loading Dropdown...<img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" /></b>',
        indicator: '<b>Saving...<img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" /></b>',
        submit: 'OK',
        callback : function(value, settings) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(value);
            $(this).text(json.Value);
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $('#person').append('<span>Loading..</span>')
  });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      $('#person').find('span').remove()
  });
```

Update:

Change the ajax code with this in jeditable plugin ,

```
$.ajax({
   type : settings.loadtype,
   url  : settings.loadurl,
   data : loaddata,
  beforeSend: function(){
    if(settings.type == 'select'){
      $(self).append('<span>Loading...</span>')
    }
  },
   //async : false,
   success: function(result) {
      window.clearTimeout(t);
     content.apply(form, [result, settings, self]);
     $(self).find('span').remove()
      input_content = result;
      input.disabled = false;
   }
});
```

Hope this is works for you.

Comment: but this would run if there was any ajax call on the page (which there are alot of others . .)

Comment: @leora I updated my answer. Please replace ajax code with above posted code in jeditable plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I would just do this manually. Before launching your ajax request, add a loading image to you document. Then, when the ajax request returns, remove the image from the document in the success callback.

Comment: but i am not manually launching the ajax request, this is part of the plugin

Comment: how would i be able to do this?