# ajax post not working without alert message

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

i have a problem with ajax post function. Ajax function doesn't working without alert message. If add alert message, div content will be refresh and working my code.

I have a mv3 application. And post form data to this javascript function. Like that:

```
    function Add_Definition() {
        var data = $.extend({ call: "Add_Definition", url: "/Definition/Definition", type: "post", dataType: "html", data: $("#definition_form").serialize() }, data);
        Load(ajaxrequest(data));
    }


    function Load(val) {
        if (val == true) {
            var data = $.extend({ call: "Load", render: $("#render"), url: '@Url.Action("Definition", "Definition")', type: "get", dataType: "html", data: { "groupid": '@Request.QueryString["groupid"].ToString()'} }, data);
            ajaxrequest(data);
        }
    }
```

My ajax javascript function is below.

> function ajaxrequest(param) {
>       var result = true;
>
> ```
> //alert("hi there");
>
> $.ajax({
>         type: param.type,
>         url: param.url,
>         data: param.data,
>         dataType: param.dataType,
>         success: function (result) {
>              $(param.render).empty();
>                 $(param.render).html(result);
>             result = true;
>         },
>         error: function (request, status, error) {
>            result= false;
>         }
>     });
> return result; }
> ```

If remove // char from javascript code, it will not work, (need refresh page), if have a alert message, content will be refresh with load function.

How is error?

Comment: Because ajax is asynchronous, and your alert is giving it just enough time to get the data before proceeding. Try making it synchronous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: To work you need to add async:false , and everything will be ok.

Comment: Is this the same issue with my problem (from a few weeks ago). Just found this article, my post is very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472455/what-would-cause-my-ajax-to-not-follow-through-all-commands/52473225?noredirect=1#comment91960932_52473225

Answer (score 0):

you can also direct call like

```
var divElem = $('#yourdivid').load('@Url.Action("Definition", "Definition")');
```