# How to make loop wait till ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var tblBody = '';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "",
                    data: {},
                    success: function(response){
                        // creating table rows
                        tblBody += rowData;
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    }
                });
            }
            $("#losssummary").append(tblBody); // appending table all rows
            createDataTable('sample_1', "M d, yyyy");
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Set async: false option in your ajax call

Comment: alright, so many edits to your question.Now what is your problem ?

Comment: you are doing something wrong I think. Rethink what you r actually doing

Comment: use async:false; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax#answer-25402055

Comment: Yes. I tried async: false, It's not a good solution. Is there other way?

Comment: @Manoz Thanks for the edit. My problem is for loop is not waiting for the inner ajax response.

Comment: @Ajithshetty, At the moment doing `async:false` is most appropriate for your scenario. 

You can also take use of `.done()` of ajax

Comment: @Ajithshetty Did you try with `$.when()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippets.

Here I have used [`$.when().then()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)and then replaced the `if` with `while`.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var tblBody = '',
              i = 0;
            while (i < data.length) {
                $.when(
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "",
                      data: {},
                      success: function(response) {
                          // creating table rows
                          tblBody += rowData;
                      },
                      error: function() {}
                  })
              ).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  i++;
              });
            }
            $("#losssummary").append(tblBody); // appending table all rows
            createDataTable('sample_1', "M d, yyyy");
        },
        error: function(err) {}
    });
```

Comment: It's going through unlimited loop.

Comment: did the `i` incremented or not?

Comment: No `i` didn't increment

Comment: Did `then` method executing? Or else try with `done()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var tblBody = '';
            var i = 0;
            selfCalling(data);

            function selfCalling(data){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "",
                    data: {},
                    success: function(response){
                        // creating table rows
                        tblBody += rowData;

                        while(i<data.length){
                              selfCalling(data);
                              i++;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    }
                });


            }
            $("#losssummary").append(tblBody); // appending table all rows
            createDataTable('sample_1', "M d, yyyy");
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
        }
    });
});
```

This uses recursive function to solve your problem. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `complete` option rather `success` option