# How to display responseText from the return object in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have Jquery code

```
  $('#add_companies').click( function(e) {
    var form_id   = '#'+ $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
    var result    = do_submit(form_id);
    console.log(result);
  });
```

The code get the data from the form given by the form id and do the submit, using

```
do_submit()
```

**do_submit() function**

```
function do_submit(form_id) {
  var url         = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var ajax_result = false;

  // Submit form using ajax
  ajax_result = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(form_id).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      return result;
    },
    error: function(result) {
        // code here
      });
    },
  });

  return ajax_result;
} // End do_submit()
```

after the successful submit, it return an object stored in `result` with this data

```
Object {readyState: 1}
abort: function(a)
always: function()
complete: function()
done: function()
error: function()
fail: function()
getAllResponseHeaders: function()
getResponseHeader: function(a)
overrideMimeType: function(a)
pipe: function()
progress: function()
promise: function(a)
readyState: 4
responseJSON: 1
responseText: "1"
setRequestHeader: function(a,b)
state: function()
status: 200
statusCode: function(a)
statusText: "OK"
success: function()
then: function()
__proto__: Object
```

when I try to get the value of `result` responsetext in this format

```
result.responseText
```

console says

```
undefined
```

how to properly get the responseText?

Comment: Show how you submit form and receive response and how you access it's properties. Maybe you are accessing response before it has returned from server (common ajax error)

Comment: There I updated the question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function do_submit(form_id) {
    var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
    var ajax_result = false;

    // Submit form using ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(form_id).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        //  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478322/2240375
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            return result;
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // code here
            return result;
        }
    });
} // End do_submit()
```

Comment: making AJAX `synchronous` is very dangerous. What if the server takes lot of time to respond?

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated! `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated`

Answer (score 2):

When you `return` from `do_submit` your ajax is still processing, because it's async process. That's why your `console.log(result);` is null.

Instead you can call some function that will be executed after your ajax is done:

```
-- do_submit--

$.ajax({
    success: function (response) {
        processSubmitResponse(response);
    }
});
// here `response` is still null

----

// actual logic after submit of form.
// May be moved directly to anonymous function in `success`
function processSubmitResponse(response) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `callback` to your `do_submit` method like below:

```
......
do_submit(form_id, myCallback)
....
```

and then

```
function do_submit(form_id, myCallback) {
  var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var ajax_result = false;

 // Submit form using ajax
 $.ajax({         // AJAX is Async
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $(form_id).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
     myCallback(result);  // pass this result to your callback. Gets called when response is received with status : 200
 },
 error: function(result) {
    // code here
 },
});


}
```

in your callback:

```
function myCallback(res){
    // console.log(res.responseText);
}
```

**Alternative**: **Using jQuery `promise`**

```
     ......
     var ajaxCall = do_submit(form_id);
     $.when(ajaxCall).done(function(response){
        //console.log(response.responseText);
     });
     ....
```

and then

```
function do_submit(form_id) {
  var deferredObject = $.Deferred();
  var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var ajax_result = false;

 // Submit form using ajax
  $.ajax({         // AJAX is Async
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: $(form_id).serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result) {
     deferredObject.resolve(result); // resolves the promise
   },
   error: function(result) {
    // code here
   },
 });

 return deferredObject .promise(); // return promise immediately.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and this worked for me.

`result["responseText"]`