# Reload partial view using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried to reload a partial view using ajax and jquery like this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                async: false,
                url: "http://localhost:31569/api/Event/Get/" + eventId,

                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    var ladate = data.eventDate.split('T')[0];
                    var an = ladate.split('-')[0];
                    var month_converted = Global.ConvertToMonth(ladate.split('-')[1]);
                    var day = ladate.split('-')[2];
                    var finaldate = day + " " + month_converted + " " + an;

                    $("#detailId").val(data.id);
                    $("#detailEventTitle").val(data.eventTitle);
                    $("#detailLieu").val(data.lieu);
                    $("#DetailEventDate").val(finaldate);
                    $("#detailDescription").val(data.description);
                    $("#detailNbParticipant").val(data.nbParticipant);
                    $("#detailNbParticipantActuel").val(data.nbParticipantActuel);
                    $("#detailLogo").val(data.logo);

                    $("#divLogo").empty();
                    $("#divLogo").append(' <img id="imgLogo" src="@Html.Action("Image","Event", new { byteArray = Model.Logo })" />');

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { 
                    window.location = "/";
                }
            });
```

The problem is in this line

```
 $("#divLogo").append(' <img id="imgLogo" src="@Html.Action("Image","Event", new { byteArray = Model.Logo })" />');
```

the action is not called and I get as result

**Html**

```
<img id="imgLogo" src="@Html.Action(" image","event",="" new="" {="" bytearray="Model.Logo" })"="">
```

**Javascript Error**

> @Html.Action(:1 GET http://localhost:31569/@Html.Action( 404 (Not Found)

So I need to know

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this in a .js file? Razor won't run in a js file

Comment: @Liam yes it is a separated js file

Comment: so that's your problem. You need to put the razor into your .cshtml (where it can run) then read the result of this, clientside, from this. Drop it into a hidden variable or a data- attribute then use it from there

Comment: it's not good practice to use `async: false`

Comment: @Liam please can you more explain your solution (as an aswer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you can't run Razor in the `.js` file. .js files are client side only and have no server side element. The only place you can put Razor is in the `.cshtml` file. So you'll need to take the result of the Razor code running on the server and put it somewhere where the js can read it.

I prefer to use `data-` attribute for this. You haven't put your full HTML so I'll have to use a bit of creative license here but, briefly do something **like** this:

```
<div id="somethingThatYouCanFind" 
              data-imgsrc="@Html.Action(" image","event",="" new="" {="" bytearray="Model.Logo" })">
    <img id="imgLogo" src="@Html.Action(" image","event",="" new="" {="" bytearray="Model.Logo" })"="">
</div>
```

You can alter your js to somehting like below:

```
var imgUrl = $('#somethingThatYouCanFind').data('imgsrc');
$.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                async: false,
                url: "http://localhost:31569/api/Event/Get/" + eventId,

                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    var ladate = data.eventDate.split('T')[0];
                    var an = ladate.split('-')[0];
                    var month_converted = Global.ConvertToMonth(ladate.split('-')[1]);
                    var day = ladate.split('-')[2];
                    var finaldate = day + " " + month_converted + " " + an;

                    $("#detailId").val(data.id);
                    $("#detailEventTitle").val(data.eventTitle);
                    $("#detailLieu").val(data.lieu);
                    $("#DetailEventDate").val(finaldate);
                    $("#detailDescription").val(data.description);
                    $("#detailNbParticipant").val(data.nbParticipant);
                    $("#detailNbParticipantActuel").val(data.nbParticipantActuel);
                    $("#detailLogo").val(data.logo);

                    $("#divLogo").empty();
                    $("#divLogo").append(' <img id="imgLogo" src="'+imgUrl +'" />');

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { 
                    window.location = "/";
                }
            });
```

---

I've left your Razor code as is, but it seems a bit odd?

```
@Html.Action(" image","event",="" new="" {="" bytearray="Model.Logo" })
```

I suppose so long as it produces what you want it to??

---

As well you should read [What does “async: false” do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax). Basically don't do this.