# ajax success but not post data in the another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have this simple code:

```
var addUser = "simply";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'userControl.php',
    data: {addUser: addUser},
    success: function(response){
       alert("success");
    }
});
```

this is the page that i POST to: userControl.php, **the if statement not entering** so i didnt post? but i got alert message "success".

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ //if page was requested with POST
echo $_POST['addUser'];
}
?>
```

I got the alert message "success", but the data is not POST to the other page.
Im also try out to write 'simply' with one apostrophe. in another page in the same project i have a same Ajax and its working, so why this one not working? any ideas? i need to do it only with ajax, submit with form will not help me.
thanks

Comment: what is the `windows.location` for?? that's not the way ajax works! get rid of that line!

Comment: use  async: false, //blocks window redirect in ajax  call check link http://stackoverflow.com/a/35858496/5700401

Comment: if you lose that `windows.location` and change the alert to `alert(response);` you should see `"simply"`.

Comment: i try out: 'async: false,' Still not working. and the 'windows.location' is after the ajax blocks, i need to use this to 'redirect' to the right page.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: thx alot for the help, but its stil not working, i tried to do data: 'addUser=' + addUser but its didnt work and the ajax didnt even alert the success. also tried **data: {'addUser': addUser},** and its didnt worked. i include the jQuery library in the project twice, but in Different pages (i try to remove the include from the second page and still not working. there is no error reported on the console.log() only error in the  userControl.php page.

Comment: that is the error:
     **Notice: Undefined index: addUser in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\userControl.php on line 3**

i running the project in localhost

Comment: try a var_dump of $_POST, probably now you have to decode the object catched in post

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`  return: `array(0) { }`

Comment: so no data is coming to your page, that's why undefined index.  How are you submitting data? as in question?

Comment: `$("#button").click( function()
           {
             //the ajax is here
           }
        );` 
when i click on button.
i dont understand why it is not working, in a different page in the same project i have identical ajax and its working. what can be the difference?

Answer (score -1):

Pass data this way `data: 'addUser=' + addUser`

see below code

```
var addUser = "simply";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'userControl.php',
    data: 'addUser=' + addUser,
    success: function(response){
       alert("success");
    }
});
```

and you should remove `window.location` because it is possible before your ajax call completes page will redirect

Comment: The OP's `data` entry is perfectly valid.