# Javascript global variables not updating properly

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need lines to be a global array but when I use console.log to compare values inside the function and outside the function, the inside one works fine but the outside one remains empty. Am I missing something here?

```
      var lines = new Array();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "posts_replied_to.txt",
    success: function(content) {
      console.log("success");
      lines = content.split('\n');
      console.log(lines);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
  console.log(lines);
```

Comment: You're missing that AJAX is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not regarding global variables. Its the asynchronicity problem.By the time the console.log() outside your ajax request is called, the **ajax success callback** is not called.Thats why you won't get the right value.

```
async function doAjax() {
    return await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "posts_replied_to.txt"
    });
}

let lines = await doAjax()
lines = content.split('\n')
console.log(lines)
```

Try this code using 
[Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,AJAX is asynchronous function.So, in outside 'console.log(lines)' command run before AJAX.

You can AJAX asyn:false

[What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Before your GET response come your second console.log code also execute due to ajax is not async. Change as below,

```
var lines = new Array();
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "posts_replied_to.txt",
   async: false,
   success: function(content) {
     console.log("success");
     lines = content.split('\n');
     console.log(lines);
   },
   error: function() {
     console.log("error");
   }
 });
 console.log(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using promise object returned by ajax call.

```
var lines = new Array();
  var promise_obj  = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "posts_replied_to.txt"
  }).promise();

  promise_obj.done(function(response)
  {
    lines = response.split('\n');
    console.log(lines);
    // Rest of your logic goes here where you want to use lines.
  });
```