# AJAX call is not working - why other script functions getting blocked when this function added?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

the below ajax function is not working and while I am using this one it's blocking other script functions also. I used this function on a link click to modal. I have searched a lot to fix this, but I am unable to fix. anyone could check why this is happening?

AJAX Call :

```
$(body).ready(function(){
    /////////////// Invoice Link Click - invoice link ID is invoice ////////////////
    $("#invoice").click(function(){

        var rowID=[];

        ///////// Initialize and assign row row value /////////////
        rowID = arrays;

        if(rowID!=''){
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Ajax_calls',
                type: POST,
                data:{rowdata:rowID},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success: function(response){
               //////////////// Modala ID is modal-form  ////////////////
                    $('#modal-form').show();

                    ///////// Getting Values from response /////////////
                    var data=response.inv;

                    alert("SUCCESSFULLY RETURNED............!!!!!!!!");
                    }
                });

            }


        });
    });
```

How to sortout this?

Comment: There may be some js error. See in console. What is `arrays`?

Comment: what do you see in your console log

Comment: i'm not a codeigniter dev, but doesn't `echo base_url();` have a leading `/`?

Comment: You may want to look at "async: true" [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax) to know more about why your ajax is stopping other scripts from running.

Comment: Are you doing this on a .js file or .php file? cause u cannot use "<?php ?>" inside a js file.

Comment: @Shubs — That's the default.

Comment: Also, your `$(body).ready(function(){`.. Should be `$('body').ready(function(){` or better `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @NirajKaushal Arrays coming from other function. I am able to alert arrays separately....

Comment: @popeye in console it's showing post is not defined. but post is defined na?

Comment: @ACD i am using php file

Comment: @ACD i have tried with body and document as you said. still showing post not defined;

Comment: POST needs to be enclosed with quotes `type: 'POST',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST needs to be enclosed with quotes

```
$.ajax({
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Ajax_calls',
type: 'POST',
data:{rowdata:rowID},
dataType:"JSON",
success: function(response){
//////////////// Modala ID is modal-form  ////////////////
    $('#modal-form').show();

    ///////// Getting Values from response /////////////
    var data=response.inv;

    alert("SUCCESSFULLY RETURNED............!!!!!!!!");
    }
});
```