# Update SQL Query with populated variables from AJAX functions over multiple PHP Pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

i try to get help with that question.

All in all Q: It doesnt Update my DB entry like this Step by Step Order how i think it could be done.

its a bit difficult to explain, but i try to explain it step by step with minimal and readable Code. I use the original code, its hard to convert it in reproducible Examples.

**A.1 Page ma_aktuelle_ReadOut.php**
 There is a php Part

```
 <?php echo "<a href='ma_Testende.php?TestergebnisID=&TestaufstellungID=". $row['TestaufstellungID']."&TesterID=".$row['TesterID']."' title='Test stoppen' data-toggle='tooltip' class='stoppen'>   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop'></span></a>";
?>
```

When i click this link the following javascript function is called and ask me "really stop?"

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.stoppen").click(function(e){
   if(!confirm('Wirklich stoppen?')){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.alert').show()
    return false;
    }
    return true;
            });
        });
</script>
<style>
 .alert {
  display: none;
    }
</style>
```

When i cklick "yes" it opens the second Page.

**A 2 Page ma_Testende.php**
On this Page are 2 AJAX JS Functions.
The first Ajax is asking for "Datum" via `type:get` from the following next page and wait till success (see Page B 3):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

/* function to get Stoptime for Cycle from DB.TesterCycleCount zu erhalten  */ 
$(document).ready(async function(){
var Datum;
var TesterID = "<?php echo $_GET['TesterID']; ?>"; /* value from TesterID */ 
await $.ajax({ /* First Ajax function */
            url: 'ma_get-TesterID_Testende.php',
            type: 'get', 
            data: {TesterID:TesterID}, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){ 
                var CID = response['CID'];
                Datum = response['Datum'];
                console.log(response);
            },
             error: function(jqxhtt, status, exception) {
                 console.log(exception);
         alert('Exception:', exception)
            }
        });
console.log();
        var TestaufstellungID = "<?php echo $_GET['TestaufstellungID']; ?>";
         $.ajax({ /* Second Ajax function */
            url: 'ma_TestendeSQL.php',
            type: 'get', 
            data: {TestaufstellungID:TestaufstellungID, Datum: Datum}, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){ 
            alert('Successfully called');
     },
     error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
         console.log(exception);
         alert('Exception:', exception)
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

**B 3 Page ma_get-TesterID_Testende.php**

```
<?php
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
                $sqlreadZeit = "Select TOP 1 CID,Datum from DB.dbo.TesterCycleCount where TesterID = '".$_GET['TesterID']."' order by Datum DESC";
                $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlreadZeit);
                $zeiten_arr = array();
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $CID = $row['CID'];
                $Datum = $row['Datum']->format('d.m.Y h:m:s');
                $zeiten_arr[] = array("CID" => $CID, "Datum" => $Datum);
                                }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($zeiten_arr); 
?>
```

Back with the "Datum" the second AJAX is called (see Page A 2) 
With the "Datum" and "TestaufstellungID" as variable it should be call the next Page and Update the DB entry with the populated variablles.

**B. 4 Page ma_TestendeSQL.php**

```
<?php
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);

$TestaufstellungID = $_GET['TestaufstellungID'];
$Testende= $_GET['Datum'];
$Testdatum = date('Y-d-m');

$stop = $connection->prepare("WITH UpdateTestende AS (
  SELECT TOP 1  * from DB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
  WHERE TestaufstellungID = :TestaufstellungID
  ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC 
)
update UpdateTestende 
set Testende = :Testende,
Datum = :Testdatum");
$stop->execute(array(':TestaufstellungID' => $TestaufstellungID, ':Testdatum' => $Testdatum, ':Testende' => $Testende));

    header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
```

The php variable `$Testende` get the populated "Datum" from the Ajax functions. All in all at the end it should be Update, when i click on the link the ( Page A 1) my DB entry with the populated "Datum" which i get from the first Ajax call ( Page A 2 ) from the SQL Query ( Page B 3) back to the second AJAX Call ( Page A 2 )  than with the data: `{TestaufstellungID:TestaufstellungID, Datum: Datum}`  to the last page ( Page B 4)

But it doesnt Update my DB entry like this Step by Step Order how i think it could be done.

Encapsulated is the SQL-Code working fine. With the Code `header('Content-type: application/json');` the browser tell me the following when i click on the link from ( Page A 1 )

*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

Thats why i posted all the Step i think on one point the variables are not passed right to the next page or they are empty becasue the code is not executed in the right order Server/Client PHP/JS or Asynchronous problem... 
The console.log tell me nothing. At the moment i have no idea where to start with the debugging?

Hope someone can help me. thx

**Edit:** iam pretty sure the ajax call is empty, but i dont see it in which step the values getting empty

**Edit2:**
AJAX Call is empty or is not starting.
Further invstigation:  The Ajax alert me the error part with empty exception and dont alert me the success part. So it doesnt  go to the page `ma_get-TesterID_Testende.php` or it doesnt  return back the `Datum` .
Could be not enabled Cross-Site-Scripting be the Problem?

But in another Page is a similiar Ajax Call working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var TesterID = "<?php echo $_GET['TesterID']; ?>"; /* value der Tester erhalten */ 

        $.ajax({ /* AJAX aufrufen */
            url: 'ma_get-TesterID.php',
            type: 'get', /* Methode zum übertragen der Daten */
            data: {TesterID:TesterID}, /* Daten zu übermitteln */
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){ /* Die zurückgegebenene Daten erhalten */

                var len = response.length;

                $("#Teststart").empty(); /* Die erhaltenden Daten werden bei der ID angezeigt */
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var CID = response[i]['CID'];
                    var Datum = response[i]['Datum'];

                    $("#Teststart").append("<option value='"+Datum+"'>"+Datum+"</option>");

                }
            }
        });


    $("#TesterID").change(function(){ /* Wenn du änderst und vom Select Feld auswählst */
        var TesterID = $(this).val(); /* value der Tester erhalten */ 

        $.ajax({ /* AJAX aufrufen */
            url: 'ma_get-TesterID.php',
            type: 'get', /* Methode zum übertragen der Daten */
            data: {TesterID:TesterID}, /* Daten zu übermitteln */
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){ /* Die zurückgegebenene Daten erhalten */

                var len = response.length;

                $("#Teststart").empty(); /* Die erhaltenden Daten werden bei der ID angezeigt */
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var CID = response[i]['CID'];
                    var Datum = response[i]['Datum'];

                    $("#Teststart").append("<option value='"+Datum+"'>"+Datum+"</option>");

                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

In this example the Ajax Call starts when i change the value from a Dropdown selection Form.    Is there a difference?

How this Ajax should work i try to explain in my other question step by step, how it my application should be execute.

[Update SQL Query with populated variables from AJAX functions over multiple PHP Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239790/update-sql-query-with-populated-variables-from-ajax-functions-over-multiple-php)

**Edit 3:**
JQuery Version:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Can u explan a bit deeper, iam rly new in AJAX. And how i can check it if i needn´t to parse it?

Comment: Just assign it to a variable without `myValue = JSON.parse(myValue)` instead just use `myValue`

Comment: `JSON.parse({})` try this line in the browser, it will "exactly" show your error. Then you can try this line `JSON.parse("{}")`. That's why i assume it's already parsed.

Comment: i dont use `variable= JSON.parse()` in my code

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze on which page i should use it in the console? i tryed to use it on the Ajax page ( A 2) In firefox i cant use your code because of Content Security Policy
In google Chrome it tells me: `VM63:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193705/discussion-between-kevinspaceyiskeysersoze-and-daniel).

Comment: "When i cklick "yes" it opens the second Page.". Not according to your code, it shows the DOM Elements with class `.alert`

Comment: @delboy1978uk the part  `class='stoppen'` from the link just shows me a dom element as a handler if i accept the link from A 1 opens

Comment: iam pretty sure the ajax call is empty, but i dont see it in which step the values getting empty.

Comment: i edited for further information

Comment: you should include your php with connection details in other php files. See [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317774/1675954) Also, just from looking at file B, there seems to be a syntax error in it? (from the way that it is formatted by stackoverflow..) Maybe check this. could be an SO error either.

Comment: You can use your browsers devtools to make sure you are sending the data you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is use $_SESSION superglobal; I offer it as this question is tagged as PHP rather than AJAX/JSON, and to avoid encode-decode common issues with JSON values or arrays. If you're able to, change your strategy and use client-side to broadcast data and stop normal flow in an error response event.

With a started session_start() you can use an inner temporary array in $_SESSION to attach/detach step by step data, in this example "step" array, like this:

```
<?php
// step 1
$_SESSION['step'][1]['TesterID']            = 64;
$_SESSION['step'][1]['var2']                = 'bar';
// step 2
$_SESSION['step'][2]['TestaufstellungID']   = 65;
$_SESSION['step'][2]['var4']                = 100;
$_SESSION['step'][2]['var5']                = 256.04;
?>
```

When you send data, over AJAX, is not necesarry to convert it to JSON, because you can work with $_POST object. Meanwhile, response can give to you every $_SESSION['step'] values in JSON format.

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json")
// conditions goes here
if ( $conditions == true ) {
    echo json_encode($_SESSION['step']);
}
?>
```

This way, and considering is a "step by step" process, you can chose to save an json_encode() object updating in every step, or use session superglobal to save it only when process finish, considering all "step" array or just relevant values, users id in this case

https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-id.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php