# How to Send Single request using ajax inside a loop

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I create a simple mailer for our updates into client emails, But how can I send the data one by one and process each data on server side

html:

```
<p class="response"></p>

<form id="send_updates">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="mail-list" class="mails" id="mails"></textarea>
    <button type="submit"> start sends </button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
let mails = $('#mails').val().split('\n');
for(let i = 0; i <= cc.length; i++){
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: "{% url 'send_mail' %}",
        data: {'email': mails[i]},
        async: true,
        beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        };
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success) == true{
                $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' sent!')
            }else{
                $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' not sent!')
            };
        }
    });
```

BUT! It Sends All Request without waiting if it Success or Not

EDIT:

We Want to Monitor One By One If That Email is Send Successfully or Not!

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense, since `$.ajax(..)` indeed just simply sends a request, the `success: ...` is a *callback* that is done after the request was succesfull. Here it is definitely possible that the values will be appended in a different order than how you submitted it.

Comment: look for snippets like sequential ajax, or better have a master mailer where you send all data and the BE then loops and process, that way you will have one single http request, saves bandwidth and too much to and fro communication between client server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
    async: false,
```

as shown below:

```
    let mails = $('#mails').val().split('\n');
    for(let i = 0; i <= cc.length; i++){
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'post',
      url: "{% url 'send_mail' %}",
      data: {'email': mails[i]},
      async: false,
      beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
      };
      success: function(data){
        if (data.success) == true{
            $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' sent!')
        }else{
            $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' not sent!')
        };
      }
     });
```

Refer [What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax][1])

Comment: I thought this is be ok, But it proccess all first the request then return it once!

Comment: What I want is When the Email is currenly proccessing on back end, It shows on the client side then show the results if success or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `async/await` .

```
function getData(ajaxurl , mail) { 
        return $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            url: "{% url 'send_mail' %}" /*instead `ajaxurl`*/,
            data: {'email': mail},
            beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
            },
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success == true){
                    $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' sent!');
                }else{
                    $('.response').append(mails[i] + ' not sent!')
                }
            }
        });
    };

    async function test(mail){
        try {
            const res = await getData('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random' , mail);
            console.log(res);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }



    var mails = $('#mails').val().split('\n');
    for(let i = 0; i <= cc.length; i++){
        var mail = mails[i];
        test(mail);
    }
```

Try out this method . Here the `test()` function is async and will await for `getData()` function to complete everytime . Through this ,  you will  achieve your goal .

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the UI as they happen:

```
function fetchNextMail(mails) {
  const nextMail = mails.shift();
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url:
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(Object.keys(res));
    console.log(mails.length);
    mails.length && fetchNextMail(mails);
  });
}

fetchNextMail(["x", "y", "z"]);
```

If you can wait for all of them to finish to update the UI, you can use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(
  ["x", "y", "z"].map(mail => {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    });
  })
).then(results => {
  // results[0], results[1] and results[2]
  console.log(results.length);
});
```

A working example can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-playground-i2vb4