# Delete record using jquery ajax from a table whose rows are appended using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to delete table record on click on delete button using jquery ajax. But table rows are populated  in table body using ajax on document load.The problem is that I cant access/select delete button by class or even by Id.
Something I understand is that it is due to ajax asynchronous nature. I tried (async:false) after this fix it is  working. But  google chrome is showing warning message in console, also it is not good practice.
I actually want a better way to do this?
can Anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us your code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

My guess is you're trying to bind the click event to a dynamically generated button before it exists. Try binding to a parent that isn't dynamically generated then provide a selector for `.on()`.

```
$('.table').on('click', 'button', function() { your code });
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Your warning is probably because `async: false` is blocking. It doesn't allow other code to execute until it's done.

[What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score -1):

Give all delete button class like
`<a href="javascript:;" class="someclass" data-id="3">Delete</a>`

on click event do ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.someclass').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){

    // ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'delete.php',
        data:{id:$(this).data('id')},
        success: function(data){
            if(data=="YES"){
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            }else{
                console.log('error');
            }
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: An `<a>` is not a `<button>` or `<input type="button">`. [.bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) is depreciated and `.unbind().bind()` has no point here. The question is how to handle an event **after** an ajax call, not how to create one.