# Does async: false in JQuery's ajax blocks the UI also during the callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

Does `async: false` in JQuery's ajax blocks the UI **also during the callback**

**Or** is it **just until the answer from the server is received?**

Comment: The callback blocks the UI either way. You can't have JS-Code running and at the same time not block the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes

To be more details, `async: false` means **Other code waiting for this to finish**

Read the link below to have a better understanding

[What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)