# Request multiple parallel ajax call in same Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to make multiple ajax call on same Django view so that I get all the response from those calls at the same time.
For example:
If this is my ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'',
      dataType:'json',
    });
   });
});
```

And the ajax call request this view

```
def ajax_call(request):
    time.sleep(5)
    return JsonResponse()
```

Now what I want is, if I make three multiple ajax call parallely on same view 'ajax_call' (in above example) I should get all the 3 responses in 5 seconds instead of 5*3=15 seconds that means the ajax call should work parallelly.

I tried the above format but I get the response back in (5*3=)15 seconds . So what change should I make in above jquery ajax call ?

Comment: I just want to understand the problem. So in the ajax callback, you get the three call backs at 5s, 10s and 15s?

Comment: You might need to look at ajax async parameter. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: In addition to what @Lutfar Rahman Milu said, Django also supports async functions now, too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/