# Sometimes ajax request can't change data attribut

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/store',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {

        if(JSON.parse(response).status != 'Failure'){
            console.log(JSON.parse(response).comment)
            widget.attr("data-selection-id", JSON.parse(response).comment.id)
            removeSelection()

        }

    }
});
```

This code started working after adding `async: false`. It was strange because sometimes the attribute was added and sometimes it was not. Even if I tried to perform another action on the element, such as `.hide()`, the effect was the same. I also tried, for example, displaying the message with the ID from the response, and that always worked correctly. As I wrote before - at the moment it works, but disabling async makes the application run terribly slow, and this is a problem for me. Do you have any other ideas how I can solve this problem?

I would like that every time after send request, the returned id is stored as a data attribute, but without `async:false`

Comment: You should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: From the very limited amount of code provided, I would guess that the variable `widget` changes outside the call - and changes between the ajax starting and completing.

Comment: Note also that changing the data via `.attr("data-..", newvalue)` will not have an effect if the data attribute has already been read into data.  You should use `widget.data("selection-id"...` - but of course, that depends on how widget works and if it's been coded properly or not.