# Jquery DOM events called after events following it are executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a very weird issue in chrome.

My code is

```
$('#import').text("Importing...");
$('#import img').removeClass("hidden");

Server.postService("tests", row_datas, function(data) {
    // some stuff here
});
```

The text and the hidden class are being removed after the post action has been executed.
The code is working fine in firefox.

Comment: Any chance you're using ajax in that `Server` "stuff"?

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Providing a demo at a place like http://jsfiddle.net really helps to hone in on the problem. Am I right in guessing that `Server.postService()` is a server-side method? What does the browser actually get in the source?

Comment: Yes i am using Ajax in the server stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing needed was

```
Server.async = true
```

before the server call.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions fire in order of appearance but return in order of when they finish. It would be odd for those simple `text` and `removeClass` methods to return more slowly than whatever you're doing with your `Server` object, but I suppose it's possible. If you need the first two lines to happen before the `postService`, you might try jQuery's [`deferred.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/). [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyNR2/4/) demonstrating the potential, and some code to inspect:

```
function firstThing (){
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $('#import').text("Importing...");    
    $('#import img').removeClass("hidden");
    dfd.resolve();
}

$.when( firstThing() ).then(
    function() {
        Server.postService("tests", row_datas, function(data) {
            // some stuff here
        });
    }
)
```

As a side note, the logic of your code is problematic in that by setting the `text` of `#import`, whatever `img` had the `hidden` class won't be there anymore, but that might be beside the point.

**Update**

Noticing your response to my comment asking about your use of ajax, I would suggest you read about the [`async` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457690/jquery-ajax-success-anonymous-function-scope) and see how what you're doing might or might not be blocking events.

I would also recommend reading about [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callbacks, particularly `error`, `success`, and `complete` (now, with jQuery 1.8+, `fail`, `done`, and `always`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply crowjonah. Thanks for the sidenote but its only sample and i have not done anything like this in actual code.