# How to use Delay for method execution in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am using jquery in my one of the form. where on click of submit button i call one function `QuoteDetailValidation()`. In which i validate fields. But after validate that fields i try to get all fields which have `errorActive`  class. But unfortunately i can't get it.

See my code

```
$('#saveQuote').on('click', function(event) {

    var descriptionData1 = $('input[name=\"QuoteDetail[description][]\"]');
    QuoteDetailValidation(descriptionData1);

    var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('#quote-quoteItems-form .errorActive').length;

    alert(selectors);
    return false;
});

function QuoteDetailValidation(descriptionData1) {

    for (var i = 0; i < descriptionData1.length; i++) {

        var id = descriptionData[i].id;
        var value = descriptionData[i].value;
        var costid = costData[i].id;
        var costValue = costData[i].value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('QuoteData/validatedata'); ?>",
            data: 'descvalue=' + value + '&Descname=description&costValue=' + costValue + '&costName=cost&descId=' + id + '&costId=' + costid,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var cost = obj.cost;
                var desc = obj.desc;

                if (desc != '' || cost != '') {

                    if (cost != '') {

                        $('#' + costid).addClass('errorActive');
                        $('#' + costid).prev().addClass('error');
                        $('#' + costid).next().remove();
                        $('#' + costid).after(cost);
                        $('#' + costid).parent().removeClass('success');
                        $('#' + costid).parent().addClass('error');

                    }

                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Your data has not been submitted..Please try again');
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Now What happens, When there is error QuoteDetailValidation() append `errorActive` class to fields.

By  `var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('#quote-quoteItems-form .errorActive').length;` i try to get length of the fields which have `errorActive` class. but in alert of `selectors`, it always gives `0`. But when i alert something before getting all `errorActive` Class then alert `selectors` give me perfect count. i think there is delay because of alert before getting class `errorActive`. so that it give me count. How to use it. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your validation function is asynchronous. So your `var selector = document....` will be executed before you validation function is done.

Comment: can you tell me how to solve it.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the exact delay required for selectors to be initailized properly. Whatever we add as delay will be assumption and can be short for some scen
One options using below in your ajax request

```
async: false
```

like below:-

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('QuoteData/validatedata'); ?>",
            data: 'descvalue=' + value + '&Descname=description&costValue=' + costValue + '&costName=cost&descId=' + id + '&costId=' + costid,
            success: function(data) {}});
```

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true(it is default) then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet. [Helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457690/jquery-ajax-success-anonymous-function-scope)

But I still will advise you to move selectors part in success of ajax like below:-

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('QuoteData/validatedata'); ?>",
            data: 'descvalue=' + value + '&Descname=description&costValue=' + costValue + '&costName=cost&descId=' + id + '&costId=' + costid,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var cost = obj.cost;
                var desc = obj.desc;

                if (desc != '' || cost != '') {

                    if (cost != '') {

                        $('#' + costid).addClass('errorActive');
                        $('#' + costid).prev().addClass('error');
                        $('#' + costid).next().remove();
                        $('#' + costid).after(cost);
                        $('#' + costid).parent().removeClass('success');
                        $('#' + costid).parent().addClass('error');

                    }

                }
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('#quote-quoteItems-form .errorActive').length;
alert(selectors);
//some logice here or move the above in some function and call it here

            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Your data has not been submitted..Please try again');
            }


        });
```

or use [call back functions.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Update:** try something like below It will keep async as true and keep the count logic outside $.ajax.

```
function QuoteDetailValidation(descriptionData1,submitFormOrAddError) {

    for (var i = 0; i < descriptionData1.length; i++) {

        var id = descriptionData[i].id;
        var value = descriptionData[i].value;
        var costid = costData[i].id;
        var costValue = costData[i].value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('QuoteData/validatedata'); ?>",
            data: 'descvalue=' + value + '&Descname=description&costValue=' + costValue + '&costName=cost&descId=' + id + '&costId=' + costid,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var cost = obj.cost;
                var desc = obj.desc;

                if (desc != '' || cost != '') {

                    if (cost != '') {

                        $('#' + costid).addClass('errorActive');
                        $('#' + costid).prev().addClass('error');
                        $('#' + costid).next().remove();
                        $('#' + costid).after(cost);
                        $('#' + costid).parent().removeClass('success');
                        $('#' + costid).parent().addClass('error');

                    }

                }
                submitFormOrAddError(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Your data has not been submitted..Please try again');
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$('#saveQuote').on('click', function(event) {

    var descriptionData1 = $('input[name=\"QuoteDetail[description][]\"]');
    QuoteDetailValidation(descriptionData1);


    QuoteDetailValidation(descriptionData1,function(output){
            // here you use the output
            var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('#quote-quoteItems-form .errorActive').length; //This line is excuted only after call completes
            alert(selectors);
            //form submit here if error is zero.
        });

        alert("hii");//this  line is executed without waiting for above call..
        return false;
});
```

Comment: @Jazz gald I could help..!!

Comment: sync calls will soon be deprecated and asyns:false, will not work any longer. Use callback function and generally all programming is more or less async

Comment: @BabakBandpay I completely agree thats is why I wrote  __But I still will advise you..__   But I honestly wanted to share all information so wrote about that too.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this on your success callback of the `QuoteDetailValidation` method, because the `$.ajax` runs async and after invoking the method it still hasn't completed.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('QuoteData/validatedata'); ?>",
        data: 'descvalue=' + value + '&Descname=description&costValue=' + costValue + '&costName=cost&descId=' + id + '&costId=' + costid,
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var cost = obj.cost;
            var desc = obj.desc;

            if (desc != '' || cost != '') {
                if (cost != '') {
                    $('#' + costid).addClass('errorActive');
                    $('#' + costid).prev().addClass('error');
                    $('#' + costid).next().remove();
                    $('#' + costid).after(cost);
                    $('#' + costid).parent().removeClass('success');
                    $('#' + costid).parent().addClass('error');
                }
            }
            // Here you know that the elements will have the necessary classes.
            var selectors = $('#quote-quoteItems-form .errorActive').length;
            alert(selectors);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('Your data has not been submitted..Please try again');
        }
    });
```

Comment: it gives perfect count but i want this count outside `$.ajax`. because if i get error count 0 then form submitted otherwise stop submission. that's why i use QuoteDetailValidation.

Comment: @Jazz Call the form.submit() after you've validated the form and always prevent the default submission. Another way is to make the call sync.

Comment: Dinevi  make the call sync. and it works perfect. thanks for your good suggestion.