# Get Date Header Asyncronously

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I want to get the Response Header Date value, but I keep getting the following warning :

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

**My code :**

```
function getxmlhttp () {
    // although IE supports the XMLHttpRequest object, but it does not work on local files.
    var forceActiveX = (window.ActiveXObject && location.protocol === "file:");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest && !forceActiveX) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {}
    }
    alert ("Your browser doesn't support XML handling!");
    return null;
};

function srvTime(){
    xmlHttp = getxmlhttp();
    //xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    //need to send this to a non-volitile page
    xmlHttp.open('GET',"blank.php",false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    console.log("raw " + xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date"));
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
};
```

When I switch this line:

```
xmlHttp.open('GET',"blank.php",true);
```

To be true, the value returns `NULL`.

So can this be done, or do I have to just live with the warning in the console?

Thank you

Comment: is jquery an option? if yes, then see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1457708/1437261

Comment: Are you returning any script from blank.php enclosed in script tag  to client  ?

Comment: You need to use a onreadystatechange/load handler with an async request, only then is data/headers available. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Get_last_modified_date

Comment: @noc2spamツ I wasn't planning on using jQuery, yet

Comment: @dreamweiver blank.php is a blank file. Its just so I can grab the header information from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your title states, you must make the request asynchronously. That means you have to issue the request and wait for it to complete to get the information. Something like this should work:

```
function srvTime(callback) {
    xmlHttp = getxmlhttp();
    //xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    //need to send this to a non-volitile page
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { // The operation is complete
            console.log("raw " + xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date"));
            callback(xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date"));
            xmlHttp = null;
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open('GET', "blank.php", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
};
```

Note that you must change the signature of your `srvTime` method. You can't return the data from it, the caller must supply a callback function that receives the date once the request completes.

An example of how you would use this function with the new signature is as follows:

```
srvTime(function (serverDate) {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "Game Time: " + serverDate;
});
```

Comment: He only wants a header so HEAD is probably a better verb.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, that's true. To clarify, my intent was to modify his existing code just enough to work. Now that you mention it, though, you should be able to get the header at `readyState == 2` (headers received), so that would be another optimization.

Comment: @JackA. OK so the one thing I dont understand is the "callback". Can you explain or direct me somewhere that explains how to get the information from there? Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Rest of my code:
    `var updateClock = function() {
        function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
        }

        var st = srvTime();
        var now = new Date(st);
        var s = pad(now.getHours()) + ':' +
                    pad(now.getMinutes()) + ':' +
                    pad(now.getSeconds());
                document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "Game Time: " + s;

                var delay = 1000;
                setTimeout(updateClock, delay);
                console.log("Time Updated: " + st);
                now = "";
            };`

Comment: A "callback" is a reference to a function that will be called when an asynchronous process completes. This is a very fundamental concept for working with JavaScript, so if you are not familiar with this, you'll need to do some study. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: @JackA. I will very much not disagree with you on that. I know I need to study up on this. Thank you again for all your input!