# jquery unable to access function parameter inside function with an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
hitUrl = function (searchUrl, nbCity) {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { "sourceid": "1" },
        url: '/webapi/xyz/abc/?' + searchUrl,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (json) {
            D_usedSearch.similarCars.showSimilarCarLink(searchUrl); 
});
```

When i put breakpoint on 1st line of success of this jquery success callback, i am unable to access 'searchUrl' in console. It is undefined.

How do i access this?

Comment: Have you closed your success function() because in your code I couldn't find the success function is been closed!!

Comment: It is closed. I have just written basic thing. Rest all is working fine, just that i am not able to access input parameter-searchUrl inside success

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because Ajax is asynchronous: the code from the function is executed parallel from the code in the ajax call.

Take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457690/jquery-ajax-success-anonymous-function-scope) for the solution to your problem.