# delay in reading variable from ajax using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var bbb;
var ma_category;
ma_category="Vocabulary";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create_matching_activity").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "a_category_code.php?ma_category="+ma_category,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                bbb=data.Act_Category_Code;
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        alert(bbb);
    });
});

<?php

include('ActivityConf.php');

$ma_cat=$_GET['ma_category'];
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT Act_Category_Code FROM activity_category WHERE Act_Category='".$ma_category."'"); 
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sql->execute();



$row = $sql->fetch();

$connect=null;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);


?>
```

This code reads from a database. im passing a variable from javascript to php using ajax. all is fine, but when i click to get my answer i get"undefined" as alert for first click, then the second click on i get the right variable in the alert.

what is the reason of this delay? Please if anyone can assist this issue.
thank you.

Comment: You don't have to pass by GET in your URL if you are using a POST ajax way. Try to catch in your file with $_POST your data and modify the url file with only the path like 'data:a_category_code.php'

Comment: You had better show us the PHP script as well

Comment: Thank you for your concern, i added the php part.

Comment: add async:false, after dataType:json in your ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Your alert is called synchronously, while the `bbb` is populated asynchronously inside of the callback - `success`.

In other words, right after the first click was fired, `bbb` was not populated with data yet (that is why it is undefined). The second time you click, the `success` function has a good chance to be executed and populate `bbb` with the data.

The fix to the problem is to move `alert` from outside of $.ajax to inside of $.ajax.success:

```
success: function(data){
    bbb=data.Act_Category_Code;
    alert(bbb);
},
```

Comment: true, yet i placed the alert outside cause i need to use the 'bbb' outside the function. what could be the solution in this case?

Comment: You need to set async:false; in ajax call, it will make ur request synchronous and will wait for the response of ajax call.

Comment: Thank you guys, after Jason P marked the question i found a great answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457690/jquery-ajax-success-anonymous-function-scope. Thank you Jason for the hint.