# google map not working, locations Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a problem I can't resolve. If I hard code the array (commented out in attached code) and ignore the ajax call the map function works. However, build the array from the ajax call and nothing happens. I think it must be the array itself but I cannot see what's wrong.

This is the server side code where I'm just adding a test table

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetLocations()
{
    DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
    dtSource.Columns.Add("address", typeof(string));
    dtSource.Rows.Add("CM0 8JH");
    dtSource.Rows.Add("SE14 5RU");

    DataTable dtLatLng = new DataTable();
    dtLatLng.Columns.Add("lat", typeof(string));
    dtLatLng.Columns.Add("lng", typeof(string));

    foreach (DataRow row in dtSource.Rows)
    {
        DataTable dtWork = GetLatLng(row[0].ToString());

        foreach (DataRow rowwork in dtWork.Rows)
        {
            dtLatLng.Rows.Add(rowwork[2], rowwork[3]);
            dtWork = null;
        }
    }
    return ConvertDataTabletoString(dtLatLng);
}

public static string ConvertDataTabletoString(System.Data.DataTable dt)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}

public static DataTable GetLatLng(string address)
{
    string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&key=AIzaSyBWQFCssXf-cic6HMYiRncde_4r9Paq9JY";
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (System.Net.WebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
            dsResult.ReadXml(reader);
            DataTable dtCoordinates = new DataTable();
            dtCoordinates.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Latitude",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Longitude",typeof(string)) });
            foreach (DataRow row in dsResult.Tables["result"].Rows)
            {
                string geometry_id = dsResult.Tables["geometry"].Select("result_id = " + row["result_id"].ToString())[0]["geometry_id"].ToString();
                DataRow location = dsResult.Tables["location"].Select("geometry_id = " + geometry_id)[0];
                dtCoordinates.Rows.Add(row["result_id"], row["formatted_address"], location["lat"], location["lng"]);
            }
            return dtCoordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the client side code where I alternately comment out the hard coded array and call the ajax call

```
<style>
    #map {
        height: 500px;
    }

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        var locations = [];

        //var locations = [
        //    { "lat": 51.6286544, "lng": 0.8193251 },
        //    { "lat": 51.4826440, "lng": -0.0473788 }
        //]

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SecretSquirrel.aspx/GetLocations",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    locations.push({
                        "lat": item.lat,
                        "lng": item.lng
                    });
                    //alert(locations[i].lng);
                });
            }
        });

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: {
                lat: 51.5074,
                lng: 0.1278
            }
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers. 
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                label: labels[i % labels.length]
            });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWQFCssXf-cic6HMYiRncde_4r9Paq9JY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I have searched forums so am not just putting this up without exhausting myself!!! Can anyone point out the probably stupid error????

Comment: `var markers = locations.map` this will run before you have any locations due to AJAX being asynchronous. Breakpoint this line and I'm 100% sure the array will be empty.

Comment: @George - Should just make that the answer :)

Comment: you have 2 options either set async: false for ajax call or call locations,map within your success function of ajax after your .each is called, even better call a separate function on success and put your remaining code of map initialization within that

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it's never really good advice to make AJAX synchronous.

Comment: I added the trailing code into the success section and the array is populated but still no display!!

Comment: @PaulCarey I've added a fiddle for an example, just keep `data = $.parseJSON(data.d);` in your code in the success of the ajax call.

Comment: @George, it's just an option... the best way is to call all the functionality within success callback of ajax as you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it is an option, but a [really bad one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @George, I know that hence suggested it as an option, not an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457690/jquery-ajax-success-anonymous-function-scope

Answer (score -1):

`var markers = locations.map` this will run before you have any locations due to AJAX being asynchronous.

Also your `lat` and `lng` are being passed as strings and not numbers.

[**JSFiddle For Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufdvdhkp/2/)

To fix it you could do something like this

```
function initMap() {
    var locations = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SecretSquirrel.aspx/GetLocations",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                locations.push({
                    "lat": Number(item.lat),
                    "lng": Number(item.lng)
                });
            });
            createMarkers(map, locations);
        }
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {
            lat: 51.5074,
            lng: 0.1278
        }
    });
}

function createMarkers(map, locations) {
    // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers. 
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    // Add some markers to the map.
    // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
    // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
    // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
    var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });
    });

    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });
}
```

I'll leave removing the markers down to you and name things how you wish.

Comment: many thanks George but now I have a completely blank screen. I am not a javascript programmer so miss the nuances sometimnes. Is this all within the initMap function?

Comment: @PaulCarey That's okay, no it's not all in the initMap function, I'll change the code for you.

Comment: George, thank you, that makes sense to me, got the map back but still not displaying any markers though. Array is populated, going to bang my head on a wall lol

Comment: @PaulCarey in that case, there may be a problem with the data you are getting back from your service

Comment: the data from the service was the initial reason I posted as I didnt realise there were other code issues. I simply can't see anything wrong with it although there is obviously something.

Comment: @PaulCarey maybe try one more thing for me in your `$.each` do `locations.push({"lat": Number(item.lat),"lng": Number(item.lng) });` I have a feeling google doesn't like strings as it's coords

Comment: @PaulCarey do a Console.log(data) and post the result here so we can see what is going on there

Comment: BINGO!!!  I will store this one in the vault!! Many thanks indeed. The Number() did it

Comment: @PaulCarey although that fixed it, it might be better to fix it on the server side rather than the client side, glad I could help though :)